# Ruby Dir.entries does not "see" all of my files

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
Dir.chdir(mydir)
Dir.entries(mydir).each do |file|
  log.info(file)
end
```

My problem is that `Dir.entries` does not appear to "see" the three most recently created files in the directory; that is, they don't show up in the log.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows XP.  The files were created immediately before the above code, via a StatTransfer command file:

```
# Run the stcmd file and wait for it to finish
threadC = Thread.new {system("ST \"myStatTransferProgram.stcmd\"")}
threadC.join
```

I don't think that StatTransfer is the problem, because `Dir.entries` can "see" the first few files produced by the stcmd file just fine.  I tried adding in `sleep(30)` between the two steps in case `Thread.join` doesn't do what I think it does, but that didn't make a difference.  I am new to Ruby and would appreciate any suggestions-- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what was going on, but it seems that the problem was related to a File.rename in an earlier step, not to the step I thought it was related to.  I'm sorry for leading people down the wrong path.  If anyone wants more info, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're creating a thread and then joining on it when running the `system` command directly would have exactly the same effect?

Comment: Actually, running the `system` command directly didn't have the same effect-- Ruby did not wait for the process to complete.